# How to fill nan value in pandas dataframe from value in another column and above row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have df as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,np.nan,0,0,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,0,np.nan],
                   "B":[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

Now, I need to replace nan values in column A with values from column B and one above row. for example: 2nd row for column A should be 0, 7th row equals to 1 etc.

I defined this function but it doesnt work trying to apply into dataframe

```py
def impute_with_previous_B(df):
    for x in range(len(df)):
        if pd.isnull(df.loc[x,"A"]) == True:
            df.loc[x,"A"] = df.loc[x-1,"B"]

df["A"] = df.apply(lambda x: impute_with_previous_B(x),axis=1)
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with that function ?

Comment: 1) `x` is an index (from 0 to `len(df)`), but you are using the `.loc` accessor. 2) The main problem though is: don't call your function inside of `.apply()`. Just call it on its own. 3) Avoid iteration with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'].shift())


     A  B
0  0.0  0
1  0.0  1
2  0.0  0
3  0.0  0
4  0.0  1
5  1.0  1
6  1.0  1
7  1.0  0
8  0.0  0
9  0.0  0
```